# How to show example where convergence in $L^1$ norm does not hold for continuous functions of the random variables?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges to a random variable $X$ in $L^1$ norm, and that $g: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

It is not necessarily true that $g(X_n)$ converges to $g(X)$ in $L^1$ norm. I'm trying to figure out a counterexample that shows this.

Comment: You should first ask if $g(X_n)$ belongs to $L^{1}$. If you consider only bounded continuous functions $g$ then the conclusion is correct.

Comment: So, if I wanted to make a counterexample, would it suffice to pick an unbounded function $g$?

Comment: Well, copper.hat has constructed an example where $g(X_n)$ and $g(X)$ are in $L^{1}$ but convergence fails.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_n = n 1_{[0,{1 \over n^2}]}$ and $g(t) = t^2$.

Then $\|x_n-0\|_1 \to 0$ but $\|g\circ x_n - g \circ 0 \|_1 = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! One question though, as $n\rightarrow \infty$, why does $E(|x_n|)\rightarrow 0$?  I have $E(|n1_{[0,\frac{1}{n^2}]}|) \le |n| E(1_{[0,\frac{1}{n^2}]}) = \frac{|n|}{n^2}$, which goes to 0. I think I need to specify that the support set is $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Jax: Sure, take the probability space as $[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure.